# zend_smtp and php warning about stream_set_timeout

Tags: php, zend-framework, email, smtp

I use Zend_Smtp to send notifications to users. It worked well. But yerstaday and today I had a lot of errors in error_log like this:

```
[21-Aug-2012 10:37:44] PHP Warning:  stream_set_timeout():
supplied argument is not a valid stream resource in
library/Zend/Mail/Protocol/Abstract.php on line 445
```

And the email is not sent. What can be the reason of this? Thanks.

Comment: Try to var_dump the $this->_socket before line 445. This should give you a clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the PHP doc : http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-set-timeout.php, I think your application cannot access the email server(the stream).

You can watch about :

- Update on the server (change the communication with email)
- Firewall or authentification (if you use a remote connection)

But, if you can provide more information about your configuration and implementation...